# Firebase Firestore / JS - Manage read/write access according to user's group

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, i want to manage access to some data, according to the user's group. I'm using Firestore.

Here is how i have my data set in my database :

```
groups:
  0PkuNM6RmQi0R4kNrN6E:
    name: "Group 1"
    users:
      user1_uid: true
      user2_uid: true
      user3_uid: true
  UaN0fsM8aK1lGGPKAhPp:
    name: "Group 2"
    users:
      user4_uid: true

documents:
  tGKE1rmax4fwc8xm9V5a:
    title: "Document 1"
    desc: "Description 1"
    group: "UaN0fsM8aK1lGGPKAhPp"
```

As an entry point, i have only the user_uid of my current user. I want to fetch all documents that my group can access to.

Is there a way to manage this only with "rules" from database, and by making a basic request like the following :

```
databaseDocumentRef..collection("documents").get()
```

I had some attemps with the rules but i didn't succeed in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use rules to filter documents by some criteria.  Please read the documentation: [Rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters).  You will have to query the database for exactly the data you require, perhaps by multiple queries.  Rules can only help you enforce the requirements of individual queries, not change their results.

Comment: So the only solution, is to make a query to get my groupId, and then a query to manage the document i have access to ?
Thank you

Comment: With your current database structure, that sounds correct.

Comment: And do you think there is a data structure which would be better to handle it ?

Comment: Maybe.  That's a whole different can of worms you're asking about.